# How to stop powershell Job in different cmd instance

Tags: powershell

I am currently writing a powershell script that continuously monitors system performance on multiple remote servers, right now through an infinite loop.

```
Register-ScheduledJob -Name $machine_name -ScriptBlock $cmd -ArgumentList $ip_address, $machine_name, $cred -RunNow
    Start-Job -DefinitionName $machine_name
```

This is the code I use to register the scheduled jobs, and it is located in an initialization script I have. Is there any way to call Stop-Job on that specific job from another instance of cmd/powershell (aka done in another script)? I  have to hook up powershell to a web interface, and ideally clicking a button on that interface would run a short script that calls Stop-Job on the started job previously mentioned.

Comment: Start by looking at the `Get-Job` cmdlet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849693.aspx

Comment: I have looked at Get-Job, the problem is I am in another Powershell session and the Job Names/IDs don't persist between the different sessions.

Comment: If you have Powershell 3 or later, PSSessions would do what you need. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347706.aspx

Comment: @Eris, don't think so; cause even if you create a new pssession; you will have to store the session to a variable. How will you pass that variable?

Comment: From the about_PSSessions_Details page on MSDN: "Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, the ComputerName parameter of the Get-PSSession cmdlet gets PSSessions that you created on the specified remote computers." http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847846.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do that. you cannot share state between two different console instances/sessions. Even if you look at `Get-Job commandlet` documentation in MSDN it says

> Gets Windows PowerShell background jobs that are running in the
>   **current session**.

So, if you run a job in console1 and then if you try `get-job` in console2; it will not display any job result since it's not present in that session at all. You will have to use `stop-job` on the same session/console.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Would a Scheduled-Job that runs via job trigger be a better option then? That seems to persist well between Console Instances.

Comment: @JedTan, honestly I have no idea about `job trigger` but if you think that will persist between Console Instances then surely go ahead and give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Rahul is true.
But to complete his answer, I think you should work with runspaces to launch all your jobs from a single PowerShell console.
This is very powerful because you still keep control on what's doing on every runspace.
I don't have any example on my phone but wait for tomorrow and I'll show how you can do that.